# Calling Python script from Python script, giving input and getting output, PyQt5, GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I am new to programming and I began learning Python 2 month ago, so please explain in a simple manner. For my bachelor thesis I have written 2 separate Python scripts which get input from user, make calculations and give output. I haven't used any OOP but both scripts have a lot of functions in them.

Now I have to make the scripts run through GUI (get users input and print output in GUI). I use PyQt5 and Qt Designer.
I read here on other thread someone suggested to make a class in each of the scripts to be called from the main script and put the whole content in the class. I did so and somehow managed to get input from the GUI and give this input to one of the calculating scripts. My problem is that I don't know how to get the output from the calculating script back to the main script. If I manage to do so, it should be easy to print the result in the GUI using setText.

My main script looks like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal
from iad import IAD  # here import the file iad.py with class IAD
class MeinDialog (QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi("kobi.ui", self)
        fck = 25
        self.input_fck.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.fck_change)

        self.show()


    def fck_change(self):
        fck_i = (self.input_fck.currentIndex())
        if fck_i == 0:
            fck = 12
        elif fck_i == 1:
            fck = 16
        elif fck_i == 2:
            fck = 20
        elif fck_i == 3:
            fck = 25
        elif fck_i == 4:
            fck = 30
        elif fck_i == 5:
            fck = 35
        elif fck_i == 6:
            fck = 40
        elif fck_i == 7:
            fck = 45
        elif fck_i == 8:
            fck = 50
        IAD(fck)

        as1 = str(IAD.as1_output())      # ???  this does not work
        self.output_as1.setText(as1)     # ???  

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
dialog = MeinDialog()
dialog.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The iad.py file looks like this:

```
class IAD():
    def __init__(self, fck):
        #get inputs from user
        #make some calculations
        #output:
        as1 = f_as1(epsc2_Found, epss1_Found)  #f_as1 is a function
```

The function as1 looks like this:

```
def f_as1(epsc2_var, epss1_var):
    if ned < 0 and med == 0:
        return (ned + b*h*fcd/10) / (sigma_sd(epss1_var) / 10 + sigma_sd(epss1_var / varas) / (10)) #+ fcd/10*(1+1/varas))
    elif ned > 0 and med == 0:
        return (alphar_var(epsc2_var) * b * (abs(epsc2_var) * d / (epss1_var + abs(epsc2_var))) * fcd / 10 + ned) / (
                sigma_sd(epss1_var) / 10 + sigma_sd(epss1_var) / (10 * varas) )
    elif bereich5 == True:
        return (alphar_var_5(epsc2_var) * b * h * fcd / 10 + ned) / (
                sigma_sd(epss1_bereich_5(epsc2_var)) / 10 + sigma_sd(epss2_bereich_5(epsc2_var)) / (10 * varas))
    else:
        return (alphar_var(epsc2_var)*b*(-epsc2_var*d/(epss1_var-epsc2_var))*fcd/10*(h_m/2-ka_var(epsc2_var)*(-epsc2_var*d_m/(epss1_var-epsc2_var)))-med)/(-sigma_sd(epss1_var) * zs1 / 1000 + sigma_sd((epss1_var - epsc2_var) * d2 / d + epsc2_var) * zs2 / (varas * 1000))
```

I would be grateful for any tips, suggestions and advice.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you posted *should* work:

```
    as1 = str(IAD.as1_output())      # ???  this does not work
    self.output_as1.setText(as1)     # ???
```

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "this does not work", but—to troubleshoot the issue—you might try changing the code as follows:

```
     import QTimer
     from functools import partial as bind
     ...
     self.output_as1.setText("Calling as1_output()...")
     QTimer.singleShot(
         10000,
         bind(self.output_as1.setText, str(IAD.as1_output()
     )
```

I'm guessing you will see:

1. The output text saying, `Calling as1_output()...`, then:
2. Ten seconds later, it either:

   1. Changes to an empty string, or:
   2. Remains exactly the same (i.e., `Calling as1_output()...`)

If that turns out to be the case, the next step would be to figure out why `str(IAD.as1_output())` isn't working as expected. Unfortunately, we don't have enough to details yet to help with that, but... here's a small, complete program you can run to gain confidence that your basic approach is sound:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class IAD():
    def as1_output():
        return 42

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from functools import partial as bind
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    label = QtWidgets.QLabel(mw)
    mw.show()
    label.setText("The answer is...")
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(
        5000,
        bind(label.setText, str(IAD.as1_output()))
    )
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution to my problem. Instead of making classes from my scripts, I simply made a function and than returned all the relevant outputs as list. It is much simpler this way and works like a charm!

Answer (score -3):

to use tkinter you do something like this,
create blank window as a variable:

```
window = Tk()
```

create variable with value of tkinter type, eg. Button, Entry, Label:

```
label1 = Label(window, text="random label text")
```

then add to the window like so:

```
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

change the row and column to position
make the window run:
`window.mainloop()`
 and you can change types and etc. to customise window like for instance this is a GUI which runs turtle(python inbuilt graphics) to make a shape:

`   from tkinter import *
    import turtle

```
def graphics():
    roots.destroy()
    pen = turtle.Turtle()
    for i in range(5): 
       pen.forward(100)
       pen.left(72)
    pen.clear()
    window()

def window():
    global roots

    roots = Tk()
    roots.title('Graphics Demostration')
    l1 = Label(roots, text='Graphics Demostration:\nclick the button to 
    begin')
    b1 = Button(roots, text="Begin", command=graphics)
    b1.grid()
    l1.grid()

    roots.mainloop()
window()`
```

Comment: I do not understand you, explain, if you check the tags you use and the content of the question you see clearly that you want a response with PyQt and you are using tkinter, they are 2 different libraries with different behaviors.

Comment: i know they are two different modules, that's the point i tried to make to him, that he could more easily use tkinter to do what he was doing than Pyqt as tkinter is actually better for calculations in script

Comment: Your opinion is not true, I have worked with both libraries and both serve for the same, although PyQt is much more professional (it is my opinion), they have many differences in the design and how they handle the OOP.